# Skip random messages for logging in Java

Tags: java

There are a lot of attempts to guess password in my application

```
public static boolean checkIfAddressBanned(InetSocketAddress from) {
    String address = from.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    if (bannedAddresses.contains(address)) {
        if (loggingEnabled) {
            log.info(String.format("IP [%s] is banned", address));
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to avoid multiple calls of `log.info` messages which degrade performance of the server. Code snippets above simple check boolean flag is logging is enabled. I would like to rewrite code above, to write to skip some of this events.

What is the less resource consuming way to skip some messages ? For example,

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 3 == 0)
```

Another example

```
if (atomicLong.incrementAndGet % 3 == 0)
```

Comment: Use `% 2` (or mod a power of 2) for slightly better performance. mod 3 will compile to an actual divide operation. mod 2 will be compiled as a shift (which is faster). You could also put the banned IPs into a hash and check the hash before logging a message.

Comment: Yet another example of code which would benefit from fast exit paths. Consider inverting the two `if` tests, see how your code reads a LOT better as a result.

Comment: There's a decent chance that nothing will ever get logged with `if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 3 == 0)`, or that everything will get logged, it is, after all, randomly polling time (not to mention abh's comment) - so, too inconsistent, not advised. And skipping *some* messages is not good practice. Figure out some work-around so you don't take the performance hit or maybe just don't log anything.

Comment: How about count the number logged in a given time-frame and turn off logging temporarily if this is above some threshold? Or, since you already have `bannedAddresses`, you already store the IPs, so just have a count for each which you increment and periodically log it.

Comment: @Dukeling Well, you are right regarding workaround. It should be handled somehow on iptables level.

Comment: Is this code *actually* in the slowest part of your code? Skipping logging will bite you in the ass... it just will. 
I'd caution you against 'optimizing' this code unless you are certain that it is a *significant* source of problematic performance degradation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have control of the code defining `bannedAddresses`, but would something like this work for you?

```
private static Map<String, Integer> bannedAddresses = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
...
public static boolean checkIfAddressBanned(InetSocketAddress from) {
    String address = from.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    Integer attempts = bannedAddresses.get(address);
    if (attempts == null) return false;
    bannedAddresses.put(address, attempts+1);
    if ( (loggingEnabled) && (attempts % 50 == 1) ) {
        log.info(String.format("IP [%s] is banned, %d attempts", address, attempts));
    }
    return true;
}
```